# VBA Workbook to Workbook comunication

Tags: excel, vba

I am a rookie VBA programmer I want to use one worksheet "Item Codes" to populate colomn B with dropdown values from colomn A in worksheet 1. so when I select a dropdown text value it would populate colomn B with the corresponding text from workbook "Item Codes"

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. I'm not sure I understand. Are you using workbook and worksheet like they are synonyms? Because they are not. You may be a rookie, but have you tried anything? It would help to see it!

Comment: They certainly are Synonyms there is one Workbook containing multiple worksheets. I know this code is incorrect but this is what I have so far...

Comment: now I tried this it seems more likely to work with a little debugging

Comment: Sub test() /
Dim lr As Long, i As Long /
Application.ScreenUpdating = False /
lr = Application.Worksheet("Cost Code").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row /
For i = 1 To lr /
    If Application.Worksheet("CT 03 Commodity").Range("A" & i).Value = Application.Worksheet("Cost Code").Range("A" & i).Value Then /
        Application.Worksheet("CT 03 Commodity").Range("B" & i).Value = Application.Worksheet("Cost Code").Range("A" & i).Value /
    Else /
        Application.Worksheet("CT 03 Commodity").Range("B" & i).Value = " " /
    End If /
Next i /
Application.ScreenUpdating = True /
End Sub /

Comment: sorry that's as good as i could make it look I added a / at the end of each line of code.